# How do you stop these emails from Meetup.com?

Tags: email, notifications, meetup

I'm getting this emails from Meetup.com:

> *Please do not reply to this message*
>
> ---
>
> You asked that we send you a summary of Meetup message board activity.  The
>   following is a list of discussions with new messages posted since
>   November 18, 2015 8:04 AM.
>
> ---

How do I stop them? I cannot find which settings does it.

Comment: Is there no unsubscribe option at end of the email?

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution is on the "Discussions" page of your Meetup group. Click on "Stop tracking this message board" and you're done.

Comment: I found the "Stop tracking this message board" option in a specific forum on the message board. So, go to the specific Meetup page and click "More" -> "Message boards" (`https://www.meetup.com/MEETUPNAME/messages/boards/`), go to each forum and you'll see the Stop tracking link.

Answer (score 1):

From Meetup.com :

To turn off all email updates across your Meetup Groups, click on your oval **Account dropdown**, then select **Settings**.  Select **Email Updates** from the left column.  Click the **Turn off** button under the Email updates header.

[image]

Helpful Links : http://help.meetup.com/customer/portal/articles/464957-unsubscribe-from-meetup

Comment: I don't want to turn off al emails. I want to receive the ones about RSPVs that I did as well as some other ones I selected to receive.